# How i can store cart item price as new line meta item in woocommerce oders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for function to to store each cart product price or regular price on Woocommerce order line item meta. I have created the following function for to do that but its not working. I want to store the cart product price as a new custom order item meta.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'custom_checkout_create_order_line_item', 20, 4 );
function custom_checkout_create_order_line_item( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {

$custom_field_value = get_post_meta( $item->get_product_id(), 'price', true );

    if ( ! empty( $custom_field_value ) ){
        $item->update_meta_data( 'meta_new', $custom_field_value );
    }

}
```

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as follows -

```
function add_line_item_meta_data( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    // add item price
    $product = $values['data'];
    $item->add_meta_data( 'meta_new', $product->get_price() );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'add_line_item_meta_data', 99, 4 );
```

Code goes to your active theme's functions.php

Comment: line_subtotal will change when qty change

Comment: I updated the answer with item price value. Please check.